# Convert cron expression from one timezone to another one

Tags: java, cron, timezone, timezone-offset

I am looking for a way to convert cron expression from one timezone to another one timezone.

For example, my web-client user is GMT+1200 and my server-side is GMT+0800, while user setting 02:10 to execute task every Tuesday and Thursday, the cron expression will be `0 10 2 3,5 * ?`, and I have used code as below, it can get current fire time for user's timezone

```java
CronExpression expr = new CronExpression("0 10 2 3,5 * ?");
        
System.out.println(expr.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date()));
System.out.println(expr.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(expr.getExpressionSummary());
System.out.println("=======");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1200");
expr.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.println(expr.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date()));
System.out.println(expr.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(expr.getExpressionSummary());
```

The `getNextValidTimeAfter` will print `Mon Feb 02 22:10:00 CST 2015`, which after `setTimeZone(tz);`, however the `getExpreesionSummary` or even `getCronExpression()` will still be `0 10 2 3,5 * ?`, where I want to get string will be `0 10 22 2,4 * ?` and then I can save into DB for next time fire and also another time-zone user to query setting (of course this will need to convert `0 10 22 2,4 * ?` to this user's timezone)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also having same problem.

Comment: @JyotiRanjan, I still haven't find any solution for this. I have made the conversation manually.

Comment: okay, I will let you know if I find something or code for this conversion in java. In my case, if it is done by js/jquery, then also it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to retain same cron expression, but give contextual calculations based on date timezone (so that user and serverside get next execution based on their timezones for same expression), you may use [cron-utils](http://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils), which provides such functionality. All next/previous execution calculations are contextual to timezone, since release 3.1.1.

They provide an example at the docs:

```
//Get date for last execution
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
ExecutionTime executionTime = ExecutionTime.forCron(parser.parse("* * * * * * *"));
DateTime lastExecution = executionTime.lastExecution(now));

//Get date for next execution
DateTime nextExecution = executionTime.nextExecution(now));
```

nextExecution value will be calculated for same timezone as reference date (now).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it: https://github.com/VidocqH/cron-timezone-convert

install crontzconvert

```
pip3 install crontzconvert
```

use it

```py
import crontzconvert

print(crontzconvert.convert('5 13 * * 3', 'Etc/GMT-3', 'Etc/UTC'))
```