# java util to convert cron expression from one timezone to another

Tags: java, cron

Is there any utilities in java to convert cron expression and the timezone into a standard timezone such as UTC or any other timezone?

For example: `("0 0 4 2,4 MAR ? *","IST") => cron_expression_utc_format`

for the above input if the data is converted to UTC then the resultent expression will be something like '0 30 20 1,3 MAR ? *' in UTC timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert cron expression from one timezone to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228364/convert-cron-expression-from-one-timezone-to-another-one)

Comment: No, i want to translate cron expression given in one timezone to standard timezone such as UTC and set the cron on the server. Actually the job will be submitted to server and server will run the job as per the cron expression. request to be submitted to a server which runs job as per UTC. So the cron expression provided to it will be considered w.r.t UTC.
But user doesn't know all these, he supposed to wait as per his timezone, not as per UTC